# Data types and importing in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

How do I figure out the data types while importing into salesforce? I've been struggling a bit with this issue since I'm importing from excel sheet data types aren't clear and I have to set up the format of every column in it so the import doesn't give me a bunch of errors

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you tag it [excel](/questions/tagged/excel)? It's up to you to figure out your source data types. In a pinch you can create bunch of Text(255) fields in SF, you won't get errors but the data can be next to useless. "[Garbage In, Garbage Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)"

If you're loading to custom object you can try this option, maybe it offers some smart field guessing. I expect you'll need to specify the types anyway.

[image]

https://www.salesforce.com/blog/upload-spreadsheets-lightning-object-creator/